# python code is run with config file, how to debug?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode and would like to use the debugger. My code is set up such that I run it from the terminal specifying a json config file. How can i run VScode's debugger without having to change the code?

Comment: add the json file name as argument in the launch config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can add the .json files you need here.